# Grabbing modal url paramaters

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that pops up on the screen and am passing it url params to get data into the input fields. The passing the url fields seems to be fine, however, I am having trouble grabbing the information. Is there a way to grab them in the modal?

I'm passing the params like this (and no this is not something I can change)

```
var path = baseUrl + 'modals/editMember.jsp?'+'firstname='+firstname+'&lastName='+lastName+'&phone='+phone+'&phone1='+phone1+'&phone2='+phone2+'&email='+email+'&address='+address+'&city='+city+'&zipCode='+zipCode;
        ajaxModal({
            title: thing,
            url: path,
            modalSize: 'modal-lg'
        });
    });
```

I have tried to grab data using this function, **however this is grabbing the params from the overall window and not the modal.**

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Please save me from throwing my computer out the window. I am very close to doing so.

Comment: If this is an html modal there is only one window and one url.

Comment: @charlietfl I don't understand what you mean? There needs to be a url to the modal

Comment: So you want the params that are in your string url in variable `path`?

Comment: @charlietfl, yes those are the params that I need. They are passing fine...just need to grab them

Comment: so pass that into your function. You only get window url params when the argument `url` is empty or undefined

Comment: You never mentioned another page. Confusing what you need

Comment: @charlietfl It is a bootstrap modal. technically another page. I am trying to grab the url params to place them in the bootstrap modal. I tried parsing them using the function above, but that grabs the main window's params and not the modal windows.

Comment: There are no modal `window`s. An html modal is simply html inside your current page. I assume you ajax load some content or the whole modal html but it is all still in the same page and same browser window

Comment: @charlietfl Because of how this application was built it is adding it outside of the current iframe (page) so it is not on the same page and why I am having trouble.

Comment: OK and that's the first mention of an iframe. Parse the src of the iframe or put your parsing code inside the page that loads inside the iframe

Comment: @charlietfl, like I said I have tried to put the function above inside the modal code, but it only grabs the main windows data and not that of the modal url.

Comment: Create a [mcve] . Hard to follow what you are doing exactly

Comment: @charlietfl I am never going to be able to replicate this exactly because of the complex structor. All I am trying to do is pass data to a modal and grab the data within that modal.

Comment: Fine , but it's not at all clear why you can't access the string shown as `path` or the url it generates in an iframe